# Meshlab Retrieve alignment matrix

Tags: 3d, meshlab

[Meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net) has a new highly accurate ICP alignment tool for point clouds.

But the resulting transformation matrix is only displayed as a summary in the status bar. This only gives 2 decimal places which isn't enough to recover the alignment precision.

Is there a way to retrieve the full accuracy alignment transformation matrix?

Answer (score 3):

Save the project as mlp file and check for the second MLMesh object, this contains the MLMatrix44 transformation matrix.

```
  <MLMesh filename="filename2.obj" label="filename2.obj">
   <MLMatrix44>
       0.995674 0.0517233 0.077186 -23.9424 
      -0.0525978 0.998572 0.00933903 6.19513 
      -0.0765928 -0.0133584 0.996973 20.0545 
      0 0 0 1 
   </MLMatrix44>
  </MLMesh>
```

The file also contains the transformation matrix for the first mesh, but this should be identity